# Change Kernel recipe used by qemux86 machine

Tags: linux-kernel, directory-structure, yocto

I've decide to change the Kernel which is used by Yocto (as a learning exercise) but i don't know where the Kernel which is used by Yocto is stored. I understand that it is stored in a recipe but i have no clue, in which recipe it is stored in. Anyone know? 
I'm literally typing a handful of commands (listed below) feel free to do it on your machines.

```
 $ git clone http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky
 $ cd poky
 $ git checkout -b fido origin/fido
 $ source oe-init-build-env
 $bitbake core-image-minimal
 $runqemu qemux86
```

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange. Please see if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't know where the Kernel which is used by Yocto is stored.

The configuration file `poky/meta/conf/machine/include/qemu.inc` has the following lines

```
   # Use a common kernel recipe for all QEMU machines
   PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-yocto"
```

This directs bitbake to look for kernel recipes under path ***poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/***

Now at that path you'll notice two recipes

- linux-yocto_4.1.bb
- linux-yocto_4.4.bb

By design bitbake will use **linux-yocto_4.4.bb**, i.e., 4.4 kernel will be built for machine qemux86. That is because, bitbake is designed to prefer the highest recipe version.

> I've decide to change the Kernel which is used by Yocto (as a learning exercise)

In the configuration file I pointed at the beginning of this answer, you can add one more line

```
   PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto = "4.1%"
```

Adding this one line will make bitbake use **poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_4.1.bb** recipe, i.e., 4.1 kernel for qemux86.